# Android Game Development Using Java: parameter can't be resolved

Tags: android, arrays, class, this

I am developing an android board game and I am stuck with an error from one of my parameters. It is a mancala-based game with a view (`TableView.class`) containing rows of pits with stones in then, and a main activity (`Game.class`). I am attempting to define a pit and its contents.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
public class Game extends Activity {

int pitIndex, pitContents;
int _pitContents=4;
int pitsPerRow=5;


//more code here .......

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        table_view = getInitialTableView();
        tableView = new TableView(this);
        setContentView(tableView);
        tableView.requestFocus();
//...more code here
//

// ...


// define a playing pit
public int Pit(int pitIndex, int pitContents) {
this.pitIndex=pitIndex;
this.pitContents=pitContents;

}

// set player1's pits and populate them
public int Player1Pits[] = new int[16*2];
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (2 * pitsPerRow); i++) {
            if (i < pitsPerRow) {
                Player1Pits[i] =  new Pit(i,_pitContents);
            else {
// do nothing
}
        }
    }
//.....
}
```

The error I get from **Eclipse** is that "Pit cannot be resolved to a type" when I try to instantiate a new pit:

```
Player1Pits[i] =  new Pit(i,_pitContents);
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Do I have to define Pit as a class outside the `Game` class? 
I have searched exhaustively for a solution before posting this question. Your input will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ali. Thanks for the response. I have no logcat as of now. The program will not compile because of this error.

Comment: Are you sure you know what are you doing?

Comment: @Shaiful. Player1Pits is a subclass of Pit. I am a newbie to Java.:-(

Comment: This formatting of calling [new Pit()] only call when you have a class by pit name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of your method called Pit and make a pit class like this:

```
public class Pit {
    public int mPitIndex, mPitContents;

    public Pit(int pitIndex, int pitContents) {
        this.mPitIndex = pitIndex;
        this.mPitContents = pitContents;
    }
}
```

What languages are you familiar with by the way?

Comment: Thanks Ian Newson.That solved the problem. I am familiar with Matlab and VisualBasic and recently starting out with Java.  Now I want to add a string to the Pit class, but when I do that I get the error "Type mismatch. Cannot convert from Pit to String". How can I redefine my array (public int Player1Pits[] = new int[16*2];) so that it accepts a string (pitString) in addition to pitIndex and pitContents? I have tried to use Array but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is Pit a class somewhere in the 'more code' sections? From what I see, you're trying to do new on a function directly, not on a class.

Comment: Actually he created a `Pit` method (in the middle part) and try to create an object of that method.. :p

Comment: @Ernstsson.Thanks for your contribution. What do I have to do to make it work? Make a Pit class?